# Combine two MYSQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have to mysql queries that I need to combine:

First query will list down all usernames and passwords:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Username, Password from user");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

echo $row['Username'].' '.$row['Password'];

}
```

Second will just print the password that corresponds to a certain username:

```
$user=$_SESSION['user'];

$query2=mysql_query("SELECT Username, Password from user WHERE Username = '$user'");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{

 echo $row2['Password'];

}
```

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to combine them? What would the combined query *do*?

Comment: Why do you want to combine them?  The result from the 2nd query is already in the 1st one.

Comment: I'm going to assume these are hashed passwords... try a union https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Username, Password from user");
$user=$_SESSION['user'];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
echo $row['Username'].' '.$row['Password'];
if ($row['Username'] == $user) {
 echo $row['Password'];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first result array has already the answer. I am assuming your username is unique. 
So you can get combine them like this.

```
$user=$_SESSION['user'];
$query=mysql_query("SELECT Username, Password from user");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo $row['Username'].' '.$row['Password']."<br />";
  if($row['Username']==$user)echo "THIS IS THE PASSWORD: ".$row['Password'];
}
```

Are they the hash passwords? Or do you do any kind of encryption?

Comment: Yes, I use sha1 for passwords. Thanks for the answer!